# Proof that Y|X is serially independent given the assumptions of linear regression

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

Linear regression can be formulated as either:

$E(Y|x)=\theta^\intercal x$

or

$Y|x=\theta^\intercal x + \epsilon$

which implies $\epsilon = Y|x - E(Y|x)$.

The assumptions are:

1. The relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is linear
2. $\epsilon\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ (Gaussian error, homoscedasticity)
3. $\epsilon$ and $X$ are independent (Additive error)
4. $\epsilon$ is serially independent

From these assumptions, how do we conclude that $Y|X$ is serially independent?

In other words, why is the following true?:

$p(y^{(1)},\ldots, y^{(n)}|x^{(1)},\ldots, x^{(n)})=p(y^{(1)}|x^{(1)})\cdots p(y^{(n)}|x^{(n)})$

Comment: I think it is becasue 4.$\epsilon$ is serially independent which is one of your assumptions.

Comment: @DeepNorth Thanks, what I'm mostly confused about is how the pdf of x is not involved in the proof. We can't use the pdf of x because we make no distributional assumptions about x.